# java "generic generic type"

Tags: java, generics

In my application, I have a Board. A Board consists of cell. Each cell has an int value.
There are few types of Boards that will extend Board.
Each type of Board will represent the cells differently. For example, one would use a List and anothr will use a Tree.

So this is what is tried:

```
public abstract class Board<T> {
    T<Cell> cells;  //error - The type T is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Cell>

    protected abstract void setValues(T<Integer> values);
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't make T a generic type.
How do I implement that?

Comment: Perhaps make `T extends Collection` in your class signature?  That way you can use `List` or `Tree`?  Not too confident in my suggestion, I'd like critique if necessary.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the class you'll use for `T`? Usually, you'd just nest the parameterized type in the generic declaration for `Board`, but it doesn't make sense to have an unrestricted `T` parameter that you then expect to be generic; what if `T` is `Integer`? Furthermore, is this a case where just subclassing `Board` would make more sense than having a generic parameter on it? After all, the client will have to be aware of the differences if it's providing the representation for them.

Comment: It would be really helpful to sketch two use-cases. Particularly how you intend to use the `setValues` method, how the board should internally access its `cells`, and what types `T` can be (when you say "Tree", do you mean a `TreeSet`? If it always is a `Collection`, then this is fairly trivial...)

Comment: @chrylis How do I get `T` to be generic?

Comment: Have you considered using Scala which supports higher-kinded types?  You seem to be just starting out, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your approach too complicated. Peter.petrov is close to what I will do.

If List and Tree (TreeSet) is what you need, both implements interface Collection so why not use this ?? Do you need anything extra to work with beside of add, removing, iterating ?

[Collection (Javadoc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

So you class could look (I added little bit Java8 features)

```
public abstract class Board {
    Collection<Cell> cells;  

    // Don't need to be abstract
    protected void setValues(Collection<Integer> values) {
        Stream<Cell> transformed = values.stream().map(Cell::new);
        cells.addAll(transformed.collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}

class Cell {
    private Integer value;

    Cell(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If you need (for some reason something extra, extend this class and implement/override methods that will do special behaviour). Hopefully I helped, but I really don't see a use case for your example.

Comment: Can you explain the code in `setVaues`? Also, what would happen if `cells` is a List and `values` is a Tree?

Comment: First line is new (Java8) and does that transform collection (could be List, Set, etc) into Stream<String> and then do map from Integer to Cell. Before Java8 you will need For-each loop and anonymous Function implementation, but with Java8 you could easily use CONSTRUCTOR REFERENCE and it will take each element (which is String) and look for constructor with String and contract Cell object. Map returns Stream<Cell> and you will transform it into Collection (which will be your internal representation.

Comment: About second half of question. There isn't such thing as Tree. There is TreeSet. It will work same way (if you switch from Collection<String> to TreeSet<String>.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have something like:

```
public abstract class Board<T extends OtherGenericClass<TT>, TT> {
    T cells;
    public Board(T cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }
    protected abstract void setValues(T<Integer> values);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell<Integer> cells = new Cell<Integer>();
        Board<Cell<Integer>,Integer> board = new Board<Cell<Integer>,Integer>(cells);
    }
}
```

This does not seem like what you want though...I think you would rather have this:

```
public abstract class Board<T> {
    Cell<T>[] cells;
    public Board(Cell<T>[] cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }
}
```

with a `Cell` class:

```
public abstract class Cell<T> {
    T cellValue;
    public Cell(T cellValue) {
        return cellValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public abstract class Board<T extends OtherGenericClass<TT>, TT>` gives me the exact same error

Comment: @AmitK sorry I forgot to change part of the code =p
Check again

Comment: This doesn't seems to help me with the different structures of cells

Comment: @AmitK did you even read my suggestion?  The first is a patchwork attempt to make what you tried work, the second is a much better way to handle `Cell`s that can contain a `Generic` object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see much of a need to use generics here.

```
public abstract class Board {
    Holder<Cell> cells;   

    protected abstract void setValues(Integer[] values);
}
```

Now have your List and Tree implement/extend Holder.
You can have 2 classes ListHolder and TreeHolder which both hold
cells but one is backed by a List, the other one by a Tree.

Actually maybe it makes more sense the `setValues` to be a
method on Holder which both ListHolder and TreeHolder implement.